# Inflation-restrction sequence for maximal $S$-ramified extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology, number-fields, short-exact-sequences, ramification

Let $K$ be a number field. Let $G_K$ be an absolute Galois group of $K$. Let $M$ be a $G_K$-module and $L/K$ be a finite extension.

There is a inflation-restriction exact sequence,

$0\to H^1(Gak(L/K), M^{Gal(L/K)})\to H^1(G_K,M)\to H^1(G_{\overline{K}/L},M)$.

My question is, can we consider analogue of this sequence for maximal $S-$ramified extension ?

Let $S$ be a set of places of $K$ containing Archimedean places.
Let write $K_S$ for the largest subfield of $\overline{K}$ containing $K$ that is ramified only at primes in $S$.

Let $S'$ be set of places of $L$ above $S$.

For example, does there exists an exact sequence

$0\to H^1(Gak(L/K), M^{Gal(L/K)})\to H^1(Gal(K_S/K),M)\to H^1(Gal(L_{S'}/L),M)$ ?

Comment: Are you willing to assume that L is contained in K_S?

Comment: @David Loeffler.
Even though I am also  interested in cases where $L \subset K_S$ is not true, upon further consideration, I realize that having that assumption $L \subset K_S$ is actually not a problem for my purpose.

Comment: Then K_S = L_S and it is a straightforward application of induction-restriction.